# How to recursively enumerate all possible arrays where each element has an upper bound?

Tags: c++, recursion

For example, I want to enumerate all arrays in the range `[0,0,0,0] ~ [3,4,5,6]`.

I can access whole possible cases with loops but my brain fried when I try to implement it recursively.

I know it is a kind of useless questions myself but curious.

Comment: The range in the question description differs from that in the question title. Please specify the correct range.

Comment: @vishal-wadhwa You will understand after you read below answer :)

Comment: What I meant to say was that the range in the question title was `{0,0,0}~{4,5,6}` and in the description it was `{0, 0, 0, 0} ~ {3, 4, 5, 6}`. So, I was asking whether you want the answer for 3 digit or 4 digit case or a general case. See your old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49344868/revisions). :)

Comment: @vishal-wadhwa thanks for you correction :) Time to improve English....xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to visit each state once, it's just better and easier to use the loop. One way to do the recursive version would be this.

```
bool checkArray(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    if (d > 6) {
        d = 0;
        ++c;
    }
    if (c > 5) {
        c = 0;
        ++b;
    }
    if (b > 4) {
        b = 0;
        ++a;
    }
    if (a > 3)
        return false;

    if (array[a][b][c][d] == something)
        return true;

    return checkArray(a,b,c,d+1);
}
```

Comment: I can't believe that I couldn't find this way. Thanks! It was really helpful.